# nodejs json dynamic property

Tags: json, node.js, parsing

I want to make a simple app that receives a json object, and a path. The result is the value of that path, for example:

```
node {"asd":{"qwe":"123", "ert":"465"}} asd.qwe
```

should return me: `123`

I'm using this:

```
var result = JSON.parse(jsonToBeParsed);
console.log(result["asd"]["qwe"]);
```

But I want to be able of getting the values dinamically with a string.
Is there a way to do something like this? :

```
var result = JSON.parse(jsonToBeParsed);
var path = "asd.qwe" //or whatever
console.log(result[path]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var current = result,
    path = 'asd.qwe';

path.split('.').forEach(function(token) {
  current = current && current[token];
});

console.log(current);// Would be undefined if path didn't match anything in "result" var
```

**EDIT**

The purpose of `current && ...` is so that if `current` is undefined (due to an invalid path) the script won't try to evaluate `undefined["something"]` which would throw an error. However, I've just realized the if `current` happens to be falsy (i.e. `false` or zero or an empty string) this would fail to look up the property in `token`. So probably the check should be `current != null`.

**ANOTHER EDIT**

Here's a much better, idiomatic way to do it in one line, using the [Array.reduce() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
path.split('.').reduce(
  function(memo, token) {
    return memo != null && memo[token];
  },
  resultJson
);
```

This is also better because it doesn't require ANY `var`s

Comment: Cheers. I added another solution. It's much better.